# Is there a better notation for this (distributions)?

Tags: notation, distribution-theory

Usually, a distribution $T$ applied to a test function $\varphi$ can be written as $
\langle T, \varphi \rangle$ instead of $T(\varphi)$. But, there is also this notation with quotes that I found in our notebook
$$
\forall \varphi\in\mathcal{D}: \langle "T(ax)", \varphi \rangle = \frac{1}{|a|} \langle T, "\varphi(\frac{x}{a})" \rangle
$$

I know that we can use $\varphi(\frac{\cdot}{a})$ instead, but we can't write $T(a \times \cdot)$, I assume.

So, is there any better way to write the definition above?

Edit: I am sorry if my question caused confusion, but it is not about the dilation operation, but rather about the "quote" notation itself.

For example,
$$
\langle \delta, "\varphi(x+a)" \rangle
$$
or,
$$
\langle "T_{\exp(x)}", \varphi \rangle
$$

Is there any general notation that can be used for these cases instead of double quotes?

Comment: if $a$ is a scalar then you can use $T(a\,\cdot\,  )$ or $T\circ \tau_a$ for $\tau _a(x):=ax$

Comment: After your edit I still think my answer applies. The quotation marks are a quick way to notate a composition of functions. A more correct notation would be to define the function being composed with, a translation, dilation or whatever it may be, and then use this in the notation. Like I did in my answer with $M_a$.

Comment: @stochastic-conch I understand it does. But, do I need to define an operator in each case? Is there no general solution/notation?

Comment: Yes, I believe you need to define an operator in each case, and that is presumably why the author is opting for the notation with quotation marks instead to avoid doing this.

Answer (score 2):

I guess if you let $M_a$ be the operator $M_a\varphi(x)=\varphi(ax)$, then for any $f\in L^1_\mathrm{loc}$ we have
$$
\langle M_af,\varphi\rangle=\frac{1}{\lvert a\rvert}\langle f,M_{a^{-1}}\varphi\rangle
$$
by a change of variables, so it makes sense to define $\langle M_aT,\varphi\rangle:=\lvert a\rvert^{-1}\langle T,M_{a^{-1}}\varphi\rangle$, where of course $a\neq 0$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It does answer part of my question. However, I am looking for a general notation if it exists. I do appreciate you taking your time to answer though.